# Can we conclude that $E(XY)=E(E(XY|\mathcal{F}))=E(XE(Y|\mathcal{F}))<E(X\cdot C)=CE(X)?$

Tags: calculus, probability, expected-value

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, assume that $X$ and $Y$ are conditional independents under $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}$ and $X\in \mathcal{F}$. If $E(Y|\mathcal{F})<C$ for some constants $C>0$, can we conclude that
$$E(XY)=E(E(XY|\mathcal{F}))=E(XE(Y|\mathcal{F}))<E(X\cdot C)=CE(X)?$$

Comment: This works if $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative random variables.  Also, I don't see where you used conditional independence.  It looks like it's not needed.  (In general, $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables factor out of the conditional expectation.)

Comment: @PeterMorfe Why need $X$ is non-negative? Here I used $E(XY|X)=XE(Y|X)$ for $E|Y|<\infty$ and $E|XY|<\infty$.

Comment: Suppose that $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=0.5$ and let $Y$ be such that $\mathbb{E}[XY]  > 0$. For example $Y=1_{\{X>0\}}.$ Then $0.5 = \mathbb{E}[XY] < C\mathbb{E}[X] = 0.$ Contradiction

Comment: @Wywana But why the Theorem 4.1.14. in Durret's textbook did not say that the $X$ need to be non-negative? I am confused now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude the inequality in the case that $X\operatorname{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}]<X C$ almost sure, this happen, by example, when $X>0$ a.s. because in this case you will have that

$$
X\operatorname{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}]<X C\text{ a.s. }\iff \operatorname{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}]< C\text{ a.s. }
$$

If $X^-\neq 0$ a.s. then in this region you will have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}]< C\text{ a.s. }\iff -X^{-}\operatorname{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}]>-X^{-} C\text{ a.s. }
$$

so the inequality $X\operatorname{E}[Y|\mathcal{F}]< XC\text{ a.s. }$ doesn't need to hold, and consequently $\operatorname{E}[XY]<C\operatorname{E}[X]$ neither.